# Como imprimir em um HTML usando PHP uma lista de itens tipo <ul> com 3 tipos diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql, css, html5

Tenho uma tabela em MySQL chamada Plans com os campos:

[image: Campos da Tabela Plans]

Que é uma tabela de planos de assinatura de um site, o modelo final é como mostra a imagem a seguir:

[image: Resultado final desejado]

Onde:

- name = Nome do Plano
- op1 = Primeira vantagem do plano
- op2 = Segunda    vantagem do plano
- op3 = Terceira vantagem do    plano
- price = preço do    plano

Preciso imprimir estas informações da tabela Plans neste HTML, com o mesmo design (CSS) utilizando PHP. Segue o código do HTML desta tabela de preços, sem esta ligação apenas o HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="table_three">
                            <div class="price_table">
                                <div class="price_table_inner">
                                    <div class="price_header color_carrot">
                                        <h3>Iniciante</h3>
                                        <p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras Iniciantes</p>
                                        <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price color_carrot2">
                                        <h1>R$ 10,00</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="service_list">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>10 créditos de anúncio</li>
                                            <li>Equivalente à 10 compras</li>
                                            <li>Não há validade de expiração dos créditos</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <form action="login.html" method="POST">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_carrot3" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="table_three">
                            <div class="price_table">
                                <div class="price_table_inner">
                                    <div class="price_header color_amethyst">
                                        <h3>Intermediário</h3>
                                        <p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras já com clientela</p>
                                        <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price color_amethyst2">
                                        <h1>R$ 30,00</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="service_list">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>30 créditos de anúncio</li>
                                            <li>Equivalente à 30 compras</li>
                                            <li>Não há validade de expiração dos créditos</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_amethyst3" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="table_three">
                            <div class="price_table">
                                <div class="price_table_inner">
                                    <div class="price_header color_sunflower">
                                        <h3>Premium</h3>
                                        <p>Vovós Cozinheiras Premium</p>
                                        <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="price color_sunflower2">
                                        <h1>R$ 99,00</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="service_list">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>100 créditos de anúncio</li>
                                            <li>Equivalente à 100 compras</li>
                                            <li>Não há validade de expiração dos créditos</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_sunflower3" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei qual seria a dificuldade, se quiser fazer da maneira comum, *misturando PHP com HTML*, utilize:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php

    $cores = ['carrot', 'amethyst', 'sunflower'];
    $index_cor = 0;

    $planos = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT id, name, op1, op2, op3, price FROM plans');

    while (list($id, $name, $ops['0'], $ops['1'], $ops['2'], $price) = mysqli_fetch_array($planos, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="table_three">
                <div class="price_table">
                    <div class="price_table_inner">
                        <div class="price_header color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>">
                            <h3><?= htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF8') ?></h3>
                            <p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras Iniciantes</p>
                            <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>2">
                            <h1>
                                R$ <?= str_replace($price, '.', ',') ?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="service_list">
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($ops as $op) {
                                    ?>
                                    <li><?= htmlentities($op, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF8'); ?></li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <form action="login.html" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?= htmlentities($id, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF8') ?>"
                                   name="plano_selecionado">
                            <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy"
                                   class="btn color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>3"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $index_cor++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Está faltando a frase (`<p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras Iniciantes</p>`), isto está fixo e não há no banco de dados essa informação.

Comment: A dificuldade é que quero manter as cores diferentes para cada impressão.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui e marco se deu certo....

Comment: Na verdade não havia observado isso, mas é fácil fazer.

Comment: Editei para alterar a cor em cada "bloco".

Comment: Minha conexão usa $pdo = new PDO e está dando o erro " Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\wamp64\www\temp\loja_cook.php on line 109" que é em "  $planos = mysqli_query($pdo, $query);"... não sei que erro é este @Inkeliz

Comment: Se você usa PDO não poderá usar `mysqli_`, utilize o equivalente do PDO, que é o `$PDO->query()` [e afins](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Como posso pegar o item selecionado no botão?

Comment: Pode pegar o `$id` e criar um `input` do tipo `hidden` e obter isto na outra página, editei para isso, enfim.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz somente do primeiro para você ver como funcionaria, o resto você pode fazer sozinho, meu intuito não é fazer para você e sim te mostra como fazer.

```
<?php
    $select = "SELECT * FROM plans WHERE idplans=1";
    $verifica = mysqli_query($connect, $select) //Onde $connect é a conexão com banco de dados
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($verifica); //Define as váriaveis
    $name = $row[1];
    $op1 = $row[2];
    $op2 = $row[3];
    $op3 = $row[4];
    $preço = $row[5]
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="table_three">
      <div class="price_table">
         <div class="price_table_inner">
            <div class="price_header color_carrot">
               <?php echo "<h3>$name</h3>"; ?>
               <p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras Iniciantes</p>
               <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="price color_carrot2">
               <?php echo "<h1>R$ 10,00</h1>";
            </div>
            <div class="service_list">
               <ul>
                  <?php echo "<li>$op1</li>
                  <li>$op2</li>
                  <li>$op3</li>"; ?>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <form action="login.html" method="POST">
               <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_carrot3" />
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="table_three">
      <div class="price_table">
         <div class="price_table_inner">
            <div class="price_header color_amethyst">
               <h3>Intermediário</h3>
               <p>Para Vovós Cozinheiras já com clientela</p>
               <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="price color_amethyst2">
               <h1>R$ 30,00</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="service_list">
               <ul>
                  <li>30 créditos de anúncio</li>
                  <li>Equivalente à 30 compras</li>
                  <li>Não há validade de expiração dos créditos</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
               <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_amethyst3" />
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="table_three">
      <div class="price_table">
         <div class="price_table_inner">
            <div class="price_header color_sunflower">
               <h3>Premium</h3>
               <p>Vovós Cozinheiras Premium</p>
               <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="price color_sunflower2">
               <h1>R$ 99,00</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="service_list">
               <ul>
                  <li>100 créditos de anúncio</li>
                  <li>Equivalente à 100 compras</li>
                  <li>Não há validade de expiração dos créditos</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
               <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_sunflower3" />
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta que marquei como correta é perfeita. Obrigado @Inkeliz. Como uso conexão PDO tive que adaptar, então apenas para agregar aqui a este post, segue como fiz utilizando conexão PDO:

```
   <div class="row">
                        <?php

                        $cores = ['carrot', 'amethyst', 'sunflower'];
                        $index_cor = 0;


                        $planos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, subtitle, op1, op2, op3, price, qty_credit FROM plans");
                        $planos->execute();



                        $resultado = $planos->fetchAll();

                   //     $linha = $planos->rowCount();




                    //    print("Deleted $linha rows.\n");

                        foreach($resultado as $mostra){
                            $name = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['name']));
                            $subtitle = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['subtitle']));  
                            $op1 = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['op1']));   
                            $op2 = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['op2']));
                            $op3 = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['op3']));
                            $price = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['price']));   
                            $qty_credit = addslashes(strip_tags($mostra['qty_credit']));   






                    ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="table_three">
                                    <div class="price_table">
                                        <div class="price_table_inner">
                                            <div class="price_header color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>">
                                                <h3>
                                                    <?= $subtitle ?>
                                                </h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    <?= $op1 ?>
                                                </p>
                                                <div class="ribbon">HOT</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="price color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>2">
                                                <h1>R$
                                                    <?= $price ?>
                                                </h1>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="service_list">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <?= $op1 ?>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <?= $op2 ?>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <?= $op3 ?>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <form action="#" method="POST">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Investir Agora" name="buy" class="btn color_<?= $cores[$index_cor] ?>3" /> 
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                $index_cor++;

                        }

                            ?>
                    </div>
```